# Page numbering problem when text is there

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I have a problem with my template. When I use the `blindtext` package or "lorem ipsum" from an online generator to simulate text everything works exactly as it should. When I write my normal text (pictures, tables and text), it won't work! The problem begins between "normal test" and "appendix".

I'm using the report-KOMA class, so every chapter begins on a right side and the sides between are empty (no header, footer, page numbers) to have every chapter beginning on a right page.

The problem is that there are numbers on empty pages that are there from the report class (to be able to start next chapter on the right page). In addition, my appendix doesn't start on a right side.

Is there another behaviour after appendix in KOMA?
Here, you can download the hole template: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1enfawBNB9xMy0tc0JOSWxiQ2c

Unfortunately, I can't provide a MWE, because after trying for one hole day, I can't provide anything. It works without my text with nearly any text. I'm not allowed to show my text here, it's scientific work so it's forbidden. I really hope you can help me, anyway.

Comment: you said you can't show the text but you seem to have put the entire text on a world readable google drive share?

Comment: numbers on the pages forced by \cleardoublepage would be the default in most classes (koma probably has a way to customise the page style on those pages to empty)  similarly you can always just put `\cleardoublepage` before the appendix if the default is not doing what you need.

Comment: Maybe there is a figure (or table or other material not allowing a page break) below the chapter title that is to large to fit the remaining text height. Then all - the chapter title and the figure - is moved to the next page.

Comment: @ David Carlisle: What I I provide meant, is that I can't show or provide the text I wrote and that text leads to my problems. The Template is made by myself so I can and I'm allowed to provide it in every way I think and want to. The link contains only the template with a blind document provided by the `package`

Comment: @ David Carlisle: I will try this `\cleardoublepage`before appendix. When it helped I will let you know.

Comment: @esdd: This could be possible but the last chapter before the appendix begins does not contain any figure (or whatever). Only text. The figures on the appendix pages could be a problem. I will check this. I will let you know what happened after testing this option.

Comment: I do not mean the chapter or the page before `\appendix`. It was about the first page of the appendix. I can reproduce your problem with e.g. `\appendix\chapter{Appendix chapter}\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{example-image-9x16}`

Comment: Oh, I see. I will test it during the week or at least at the weekend. I will write again, if everything works perfectly or not. Thanks again.

Comment: The problem is exacly what @esdd was writing about. The picture size was to high. Thanks for the help! Is there a way to have the picture in the max. hight and length? I mean a automated way?

Comment: @esdd ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: I see there are already four close votes. One could improve the question or really just close. The question about the image size is a different one and should be asked as a different question.